# JButton won't show another jframe

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I'm currently working on a project and whenever I click the jbutton on jframe 2 (the 2nd jframe after the log in) "set appointments"/btn1, it won't show the other jframe which is jframe3.
The program itself works but the button won't show the other jframe.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Container;

public class me {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    jframe.setSize(450,350);
    jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    ImageIcon c = new ImageIcon("teethlogo5.png");
    JLabel bi = new JLabel("",c,JLabel.RIGHT);
    bi.setBounds(25,35,400,40);
    jframe.add(bi);

    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("teethlogo2.png");
    JLabel si = new JLabel("",a,JLabel.RIGHT);
    si.setBounds(50,90,100,120);
    jframe.add(si);


    JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Username:");
    jl1.setBounds(190,100,100,50);
    jframe.add(jl1);

    JTextField uss = new JTextField();
    uss.setBounds(270,110,120,30);
    jframe.add(uss);

    JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Password:");
    jl2.setBounds(190,150,100,50);
    jframe.add(jl2);

    JPasswordField pss = new JPasswordField();
    pss.setBounds(270,160,120,30);
    jframe.add(pss);

    JButton enter = new JButton("log in");
    enter.setBounds(250,210,100,40);
    jframe.add(enter);

    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String userText;
            String pwdText;
            userText = uss.getText();
            pwdText = String.valueOf(pss.getPassword());

            if (userText.equals("user") && pwdText.equals("pass")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LoginSuccessful","Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                jframe.setVisible(false);
                JFrame jframe2 = new JFrame();
                jframe2.setSize(850,560);
                jframe2.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("teethlogo4.png");
                JLabel sii = new JLabel("",b,JLabel.RIGHT);
                sii.setBounds(10,0,600,100);
                jframe2.add(sii);


                JButton btn1 = new JButton("Set an Appointment");
                btn1.setBounds(100,100,150,30);
                jframe2.add(btn1);

                JButton btn2 = new JButton("View Appointments");
                btn2.setBounds(270,100,150,30);
                jframe2.add(btn2);

                btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        if (btn1.isSelected()){
                            jframe2.setVisible(false);
                            JFrame jframe3 = new JFrame();
                            jframe3.setSize(850,560);
                            jframe3.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);



                            jframe3.setLayout(null);
                            jframe3.setVisible(true);
                            jframe3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        }
                    }
                });

                jframe2.setLayout(null);
                jframe2.setVisible(true);
                jframe2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            } 

            else { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password","Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            uss.setText(null);
            pss.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });


    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    jframe.setLayout(null);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in java and I really want to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) `jframe2.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shooting your own self in the foot with:

```
if (btn1.isSelected()){
    // ...
}
```

There is no need for this block of code -- a button isn't "selected" unless it extends from JToggleButton (such as JCheckBox) and has been checked, something that a JButton does not allow, and what is more, it is preventing the listener's code that it holds from running. Solution: just get rid of it.